add S3 trigger on a Lambda function with cloudformation worked but not showing trigger in lambda console
So I have a cft which adds the s3 trigger on a lambda function. The cft is deployed successfully and able to see the trigger successfully added  in s3 bucket properties. The trigger is also working fine. But the problem is I don't see the s3-trigger in lambda console. Is this normal behavior or Am I missing something?
I tried this
NotificationConfiguration:
LambdaConfigurations:
- Event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
Filter:
S3Key:
Rules:
- Name: prefix
Value: cft_sample/
Function: functionArn
rS3InvokeTestLambdaPermission:
Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
Properties:
Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
FunctionName: functionName
Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
SourceAccount: XXXXXX
Expecting if the trigger shows in Lambda console

Go in lambda > permissions > add event notification rule.
